# how can you increase code coverage without modifying test class?

Tags: apex, code-coverage, edit

If class has 74.5 % coverage then how can we increase 0.5% coverage without modifying test class?

Comment: You can’t. That’s not how test coverage works. Please see our standard resources on coverage, which I’ve linked above.

Comment: You can increase it with some tweaks, but I would not recommend doing so, cause it is considered a really bad practice to do so. Simply saying, you can add more code to the covered blocks or reduce it in sections that are not covered.

Answer (score 2):

As a short, pithy remark: **you can't**

If you need additional coverage, then the only correct way to go about doing that is by adding additional tests (making a new test class, adding tests to the existing test class).

Technically, refactoring the code being tested (the SUT, system under test) would be another potential approach as that *could* reduce the number of uncovered lines, but doing that while making sure you aren't breaking any tests is likely harder than just writing additional tests.

Comment: +1, but refactoring can be useful. Prune unreachable catch statements, fix impossible logic conditions for if/else/do/while/for, extract comparisons to Boolean values, remove obsolete methods, and so on. The exact techniques are circumstantial, though.